# How to compile typescript for multiple arbitrary files?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to compile typescript using a cmd line code. This works for me

```
tsc src/bot.ts --resolveJsonModule true --module commonjs --target ES2020 --moduleResolution Node --noImplicitAny true --outDir dist --alwaysStrict true --typeRoots node_modules/@types --lib ES2020
```

It starts at the given file, and for every file it imports, it clones the file structure into the dist folder.

The problem is I have a bunch of `*.test.ts` files for jest, scattered all around the main src folder, but nothing really imports any of them and as a result it doesn't get transpiled into the dist folder.

Is there a command I can run that will find all `*.test.ts` in src folder and run tsc on it and clone it into the dist folder but mirroring the same folder structure as in src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `tsc src/**/*.ts src/*.ts ...` or configure your project with [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

> I would recommend going with a tsconfig.json file since it eliminates the need for that many command line options as well as giving you the capability of `include`

Comment: it says `error TS6053: File 'src/**/*.ts' not found.`

Comment: @omega, You can safely delete that part out if it doesn't work (It works with shell substitution on some machines decreasing the burden on tsc in some instances - but not always)

Comment: Is there a way I can specify a path that targets all .test.ts files?

Comment: @omega The easiest method is to use the `include` key in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: But that means I have to hardcode every path? The files are all dynamic.

Comment: @omega, you do not have to hardcode anything, the include key can have globs (example from the docs: `"include": ["src/**/*"]`)

Comment: If I have the tsconfig.js file, what command will execute it?

Comment: Just `tsc` since it should find the tsconfig.json (or `tsc --project <path to tsconfig.json>` if it doesn't) as long as all settings are correct